# blogger "dynamic views" header css

Tags: css, header, blogger, blogspot, blogger-dynamic-views

As you can see the header for my blog https://blog.cryformeqq.icu currently has drop shadow for the title, plus there's this weird gradient on top of the background color (which is supposed to be the same as the lighter grey under the navigation bar)

Anyone have any ideas? I tried a bunch of stuff I found online, none if it worked though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of this style to get rid of the gradient: `#header .header-bar { background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.05) ); background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)) );`.
Delete `#header .header-bar .title h1 { text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }`  to get rid of the text shadow.

Or overwrite with `header .header-bar .title h1 { text-shadow: none; }` and `#header .header-bar { background-image: none; }`

Comment: I remember that blogger has an "Advanced" section somewhere to overwrite the theme CSS. You might have to consider specificity of the styles, though.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! You're a lifesaver.

Can I ask you how you figured that out so quickly? Like, how can I figure this stuff out myself from now on? What tools do you use to inspect it and stuff? I'd like to learn

Comment: I would start with some basic tutorials on "Google Chrome Developer Tools". It's a built in tool in your browser, you can see the code of your webpage with. 
If you know some basic CSS you can then find the styles you want on your pages - and modify them.

Comment: Just google for "Chrome Developer Tools Tutorial / Crash Course". There is, of course, also Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools 
PS You can accept the answer, if it worked out for you ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry, let me see how to do that. But yeah, I've been messing around with it for a bit, and I think I kinda got the hang of it. Thank you!